# OpenGL refusing to load texture as a cubemap

Tags: python, opengl, textures

When I try to bind an image to a cubemap, OpenGL throws an 'invalid value' error on the function glTexImage2D. The error is only thrown when the target parameter is GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X; I'm using a similar function for loading other textures with GL_TEXTURE_2D, and it's working fine.

```
def loadCubemap(self, faces, interpolation=GL_LINEAR):
    cubemap = glGenTextures(1)
    self.__textures.append(cubemap)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, cubemap)

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, interpolation)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, interpolation)

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0)

    for i in range(len(faces)):
        texture = self.__decodeTextureFile(faces[i])
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_RGBA, texture[1], texture[2], 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture[0])

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0)
    return cubemap

def __decodeTextureFile(self, path):
    textureImage = pygame.image.load(path)
    textureData = pygame.image.tostring(textureImage, "RGBA", 1)
    width = textureImage.get_width(); height = textureImage.get_height()
    return textureData, width, height
```

The error in full:

```
  File "src/latebind.pyx", line 39, in OpenGL_accelerate.latebind.LateBind.__call__
  File "src/wrapper.pyx", line 318, in OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper.Wrapper.__call__
  File "src/wrapper.pyx", line 311, in OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper.Wrapper.__call__
  File "src/errorchecker.pyx", line 58, in OpenGL_accelerate.errorchecker._ErrorChecker.glCheckError
OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError(
    err = 1281,
    description = b'invalid value',
    baseOperation = glTexImage2D,
    pyArgs = (
        34069,
        0,
        GL_RGBA,
        4096,
        3072,
        0,
        GL_RGBA,
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xf...,
    ),
    cArgs = (
        34069,
        0,
        GL_RGBA,
        4096,
        3072,
        0,
        GL_RGBA,
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xf...,
    ),
    cArguments = (
        34069,
        0,
        GL_RGBA,
        4096,
        3072,
        0,
        GL_RGBA,
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xf...,
    )
)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've tried changing the colour channels used for loading the texture, and I'm pretty sure this isn't the problem, I'm using PyOpenGL as well as PyOpenGL_accelerate.

Comment: Are width and height within the allowed range? The spec only mandates 1024 iirc, you should check GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE.

Comment: @IGarFieldl I just checked the width and height and this was the issue, after adjusting the image the problem is fixed.

Comment: @IGarFieldI "The spec only mandates 1024 iirc," _which_ spec? Non-Ancient versions of the OpenGL spec mandate 16384.

Comment: I was going by the minimum stated in Khronos's docs: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml

Comment: Those ref pages aren't a spec, and they are notoriously  incomplete, misleading, outdated and sometimes flat-out wrong.